# Putting physical and non-physical together

Tags: style

Is it good styling in English to place physical-thing and non-physical-thing nouns in one row?

> There are many kinds of **creatures** and **cultural heritage** in the
>   sea.

Here it looks like "many kinds" is related to both "creatures" (physical) and "cultural heritage" (doesn't strike me as totally physical) and both "many kinds" are in the sea.

Does it sound okay in English?

[image]

Comment: *There are many kinds of cultural heritage in the sea* just doesn't sound like the kind of thing a native Anglophone would say. Not so much because of the *syntax* as because it's such a strange concept (which I realise might not be the case for some speakers of other languages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such general rule for or against mixing physical and abstract, but **many kinds of ... cultural heritage** doesn't really work stylistically because the plural **heritages** is not really used, and **heritage** is not like the noun **cheese** or **fish**. It is idiomatic to speak of **kinds of cheese** but **kinds of heritage** requires a very esoteric context to make decent sense.

So, it is not really the *combination* of the physical (creatures) with the abstract (heritage) that is the problem here. Rather, it is that **many kinds of ...** is understood to apply to both grammatical objects of **of**, **creatures** and **cultural heritage**, but the word **kinds** doesn't go well with the latter.

Also, creatures are **in** the sea in a very different way that heritage is **in** the sea.  Stylistically, when clarity and immediate intelligibility are the goals, you don't want to have a preposition require different meanings for each of its objects:

> He arrived in the nick of time and a taxi.

Comment: The terms [Zeugma and Syllepsis](https://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/writing-zeugma-and-syllepsis.php) come to mind.

Comment: They used to use mercury to treat syllepsis.

Comment: Indeed - I remember when I had syllepsis I took mercury and to my bed for a week!